# Snowflake - Rebuild Table With Clustering

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I understand when clustering is enabled Snowflake will run a background task to automatically cluster your records. There are situations where I want to rebuild an entire table or populate a new table with an insert into select statement. When I do this I find that the new table is built unclustered even when I have predefined the clustering. It seems wasteful to load the table first, then rearrange it.

Is there anyway to *convince* snowflake to use the clustering i've defined when rebuilding a table or loading a new table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` that matches `CLUSTER BY` to have the data clustered at the same time its ingested:

```sql
create or replace table delete_test_cluster
cluster by (a, b)
as
select *
from (select 1 a, 2 b)
order by a, b
```

Comment: Makes sense- thank you!

Comment: Btw, that's how dbt handles `cluster by` in Snowflake too: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/snowflake-configs#using-cluster_by